# JWPlayer starts playing New audio stream after 30 second of old song play in new browser instance

Tags: audio-streaming, browser-cache, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We are using JWPlayer to play a radio stream for a online radio. The Problem is as follows:
When a Audio is played for some time say 10 to 15 mins and then browser is closed, when the same URL is opened in new browser (same of of same type or different browser) the previous audio stream plays for around 30 seconds and then the current song starts to play. I have verified multiple time, the player URL in new browser instance always point to new/current song.
Please help me so that always currently played song should start in player.